# Derivative of trig function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

Find the second derivative of $ \arcsin(2x^3) $

The solution says for the first derivative :

$ \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-(2x^3)^2}} \cdot 6x^2 = \dfrac{6x^2}{\sqrt{1-4x^6}}  $

When i answered the first derivative i got to :

$ \dfrac{\cos(2x^3) \cdot 6x^2}{\sin^2(2x^3)} $

So what am i missing ?

Comment: @Tennisman: Hint: What is the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$, see http://www.math.com/tables/derivatives/tableof.htm. You can also see this nice approach: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/1.-differentiation/part-b-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/session-15-implicit-differentiation-and-inverse-functions/MIT18_01SCF10_Ses15c.pdf

Comment: You assumed that $\sin^{-1}x$ means $\frac{1}{\sin x}$. It doesn't. It means the angle (number) between $-\pi/2$ and $\pi/2$ whose sine is $x$. Another name for it, better I think, is $\arcsin x$. By the way, if it is, you missed a minus sign.

Comment: Do not confuse $\sin^{-1}{x} = \arcsin{x}$ with $(\sin{x})^{-1}=\csc{x}$

Comment: $\arcsin(x)=y$ means $-\pi/2 \leq y \leq \pi/2$ and $\sin y = x$. Do not confude $\arc \sin(x)$ and $1/sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

> simply derivative of $\arcsin{x}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$ don't get confused in $sin^{-1}x$  and $(sinx)^{-1}$